# Do/while loop not returning to the top?

Tags: java

recently started computer programming and I am stuck on a homework assignment. I created a loop but instead of going back to the top, it starts 1 step ahead of where I intended it to. (it's all listed in the comments I made in the coding. I have been trying to figure this out for the past 6 hours so it would greatly appreciated if someone can help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Election
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
        {

            DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
            DecimalFormat n = new DecimalFormat("##");

            float votesForPolly; 
            float votesForErnest; 
            float totalPolly = 0; 
            float totalErnest = 0; 
            String response;
            int precinctsforpolly = 0; 
            int precinctsforernest = 0;
            int precinctsties = 0;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println ();      
            System.out.println ("Election Day Vote Counting Program");
            System.out.println ();

            do
            {   
                //point A
                System.out.println("Do you wish to enter more votes? Enter y:n");
                response = scan.next();
                if (response.equals("y"))
                {
                    //point B
                    System.out.println("Enter votes for Polly:");
                    votesForPolly = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter votes for Ernest:");
                    votesForErnest = scan.nextInt();

                    totalPolly = totalPolly + votesForPolly;
                    totalErnest = totalErnest +  votesForErnest;


                        System.out.println("Do you wish to add precincts? Enter y:n");
                        response = scan.next();
                        while (response.equals("y"))
                        {   
                            System.out.println("How many precincts voted for Polly: ");
                            precinctsforpolly = scan.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("How many precincts votes for Ernest: ");
                            precinctsforernest = scan.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("How many were ties: ");
                            precinctsties = scan.nextInt(); 

                            break;
                            //not returning to point A, instead it returns to point B
                        }
                            if (response.equals("n"))
                            {
                                break;

                            }


                    if (response.equals("n"))
                    {
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            while (response.equals("n"));
            System.out.println("Final Tally");
            System.out.println("Polly received:\t " + n.format(totalPolly) + " votes\t" + f.format((totalPolly/(totalPolly + totalErnest))*100) + "%\t" + precinctsforpolly + " precincts");
            System.out.println("Ernest received: " + n.format(totalErnest) + " votes\t" + f.format((totalErnest/(totalPolly + totalErnest))*100) + "%\t" + precinctsforernest + " precincts");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + precinctsties + " precincts tied");

        }
}
```

My guess is that the string response has already been determine to be y at the end of the loop which is why it skips the first step and jumps right back into the loop assuming my answer is already y.

Comment: `I have been trying to figure this out for the past 6 hours` like seriously ??

Comment: What makes you think the loop isn't returning to the top? What inputs are you giving and what responses are you getting?

Comment: try change the outer-most "while" condition `while (response.equals("y"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just need to strip your code of unnecessary `break`s and also handle the 2 responses differently. Your loop should also continue when the response is y, not the other way round.

See edited code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Election
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        DecimalFormat n = new DecimalFormat("##");

        float votesForPolly; 
        float votesForErnest; 
        float totalPolly = 0; 
        float totalErnest = 0; 
        String response;
        int precinctsforpolly = 0; 
        int precinctsforernest = 0;
        int precinctsties = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ();      
        System.out.println ("Election Day Vote Counting Program");
        System.out.println ();

        do
        {   
            //point A
            System.out.println("Do you wish to enter more votes? Enter y:n");
            response = scan.next();
            if (response.equals("y"))
            {
                //point B
                System.out.println("Enter votes for Polly:");
                votesForPolly = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter votes for Ernest:");
                votesForErnest = scan.nextInt();

                totalPolly = totalPolly + votesForPolly;
                totalErnest = totalErnest +  votesForErnest;


                    System.out.println("Do you wish to add precincts? Enter y:n");
                    String response2 = scan.next();//create a new response variable, so the loop doesn't confuse which response to break on
                    //I removed the inner loop. If you really intended for this to be an inner loop then the while(response2.equals("y")){} should be around the question, not after
                    if (response2.equals("y"))
                    {   
                        System.out.println("How many precincts voted for Polly: ");
                        precinctsforpolly = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("How many precincts votes for Ernest: ");
                        precinctsforernest = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("How many were ties: ");
                        precinctsties = scan.nextInt(); 

                    }
                //removed the unnecessary checks for when response in 'n'
            }
        }
        while (response.equals("y"));
        System.out.println("Final Tally");
        System.out.println("Polly received:\t " + n.format(totalPolly) + " votes\t" + f.format((totalPolly/(totalPolly + totalErnest))*100) + "%\t" + precinctsforpolly + " precincts");
        System.out.println("Ernest received: " + n.format(totalErnest) + " votes\t" + f.format((totalErnest/(totalPolly + totalErnest))*100) + "%\t" + precinctsforernest + " precincts");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + precinctsties + " precincts tied");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.equals("n"))
{
    break;
}
```

breaks your while loop.

You might want to loop again if user's response if 'y'.
In that case, use `while (response.equals("y"));`

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to break out if the user enters "n" but loop while the user input is "y", but your code says,

```
do{
.....
}while (response.equals("n"));
```

It should be,

```
while (response.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       do {   
            //point A
            System.out.println("Do you wish to enter more votes? Enter y:n");
            response = scan.next();
            if (response.equals("y"))
            {
                //point B
                #code
                if (response.equals("n")) //<--- this 'if' block will break the loop when response equals 'n'
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (response.equals("n"));// <----- this means doing loop when response equals "n"
```

You can see my comment on above block of code, the loop will do one more time only when response equals 'n'. But when response equals 'n', the 'if' block at above of it will break the loop and the `while (response.equals("n"))` will be not checked.